# How to make Information automatically update when account is changed?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

To get the account address of the contract that is currently logged in with Metamask I use this

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    document.getElementById('account-address').innerHTML = accounts;
});
```

How can i make it so address updates on UI when i change the account/ address in metamask, without having to refresh the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is event **accountsChanged** provided by latest MetaMask version and you can use it like this:

```
if(window.ethereum) {
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function () {
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
            document.getElementById('account-address').innerHTML = accounts;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: great, but now i dont see anything. Like I cant see any output, not in the console and not in my ui? I dont see any output

Comment: even when doing console.log(accounts); i get no output

Comment: When you console.log window.ethereum what is the outcome? Also what is your metamask version?

Comment: console.log(window.ethereum)
VM5925:1 
Proxy {selectedAddress: "0xe56570858990aa5810220f7fd54dcaaf25aea8fa", networkVersion: "3", chainId: "0x3", _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, …}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: MetamaskInpageProvider
[[IsRevoked]]: false

metamaks version is 7.7.2

Comment: Please take a look at this video I just recorded: https://streamable.com/gau1f

Comment: this is my version, i will try soon what u have shown me
{api: "0.20.7", getNode: ƒ, getNetwork: ƒ, …}
api: "0.20.7"
ethereum: (...)
getEthereum: ƒ (e)
getNetwork: ƒ (e)
getNode: ƒ (e)
getWhisper: ƒ (e)
network: (...)
node: (...)
whisper: (...)
get ethereum: ƒ ()
get network: ƒ ()
get node: ƒ ()
get whisper: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object

Comment: addres change woks in the console, however i get it print out 3 times. But why does this not work in my UI?

Comment: Can you share all of your javascript file?

Comment: yes, i pasted it here on pastepin  https://pastebin.com/wBm3rPFj

Comment: With this code here https://pastebin.com/Rbnnegg6 I was able to achieve what you're looking for. Record here => https://streamable.com/cc556 . Try again and make sure you are in the first if condition after window.addEventListener('load', async function() { ... also setup console.logs inside the try/ catch.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: thanks this works great. But why do you use 2 times in the code the getAccount function?

Comment: Great to hear. The first time is to show the address in the html when the website is loaded for the first time and second one is to make the address dynamic and change the html on metamask account change.

Comment: ok, perfect. Can you also tell me on how to get the other functions for the current logged in address- shouldnt this all be safed in array that i can just simply print out- in this case i have functions like myDividends- and token Balance?

Comment: im not satisfied with the solution. When im not logged in to metamask and i visit the site the metamask thing pops up and when i m logged in it doesnt show my address right away. I need to reload the page.
The same i need further down in my code to update address balance contract balance right away as soon as ther is a change on the blockchain.

Comment: i need my website to behave exactly like this site https://pyrabank.com/hex-2/, unfortunatly they have their js code obfuscated and i only learn to programm since a month so none of that makes much sense to me right now

Comment: Yes, the problem exists. The solution is to place the on page html address update after await window.ethereum.enable(); . Here is the correction => https://pastebin.com/mnJtxdg9

Comment: Yes this much better, so now ith this ethereum.on function if this si set to true i should now be able to get the addresses Balance and dividends etc..
thanks so much. This web3 is some weird shit

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You can mark this question as useful also if you are happy with the result.